# Select with Submit button for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form action="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delid" value="delid">
</form>

<form action="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="addid" value="addid">
</form>

<select name="option" id="option">
    <option value="delete">Delete</option>
    <option value="add">Add</option>
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Option"/>
```

I would like to choose one of the option in the select box and then click submit. It would then perform a post on one of the 2 forms at the top based on selected option. I can not figure out how to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: Both forms post to the same URL, why do you need two forms in the first place?  Just put all of this in one form and in the server-side code check which `option` was selected.

Comment: why do you need 2 forms?

Comment: The `<select>` and `<input type="submit"...` are not in a form and therefore are basically useless and can be considered irrelevant. Put simply, _if it aint in a form it aint doing anything_.... unless you are doing something in Javascript :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly You can add an event listener to the submit button and it can call `.submit()` on the appropriate form. That seems to be what he's asking how to do.

Comment: @Barmar Honestly, do you think that is what the OP has done?

Comment: @RiggsFolly He tagged it JavaScript, so I think that's the solution he's looking for.

Comment: @Barmar You are probably right. In which case the question is ___Too Broad___

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: Sorry guys, I've been reading stackoverflow for years but am new to posting on it. I did not give a very good example, I have 10 forms and some of them post to different url's. You guys are correct I was thinking it would need to be javascript but not sure, I am a php developer. I was just looking for some direction, did not need anyone to write it for me.

Comment: @Barmar yes you read between the lines of what I was looking for. I will look into javascript event listener and try to figure out how to make it call a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form name="delid" action="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delid" value="delid">
</form>

<form name="addid" action="' . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="addid" value="addid">
</form>

<select name="option" id="option">
<option value="delete">Delete</option>
<option value="add">Add</option>
</select> 
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Option"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form"); 

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let selectedValue = document.getElementById("option").value,
      inputName = selectedValue.toLowerCase().substring(0,3) + "id",
      inputElement =  document.querySelector('input[name="'+ inputName +'"]');

  if (inputElement && inputElement.parentNode && inputElement.parentNode.tagName === "FORM")
      inputElement.parentNode.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="delid" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="del" value="del">
    <input type="hidden" name="blah" value="asdf">
</form>
<form name="addid" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="add">
</form>

<select name="option" id="option">
    <option value="delid">Del</option>
    <option value="addid">Add</option>
</select>
<input id="myBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Option"/>

<script>
    var myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var selectedValue = document.getElementById("option").value; // This is the selected option value
        var formName = document.getElementsByName(selectedValue);
        formName[0].submit();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I modified the previous reply and came up with this and got it to work. Thanks!